# LUIS app not showing in Luis portal, LUIS app generated using ansible role

Tags: azure, ansible, yaml, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I generated the LUIS app(southcentral US) in the Azure portal by using azure pipelines and ansible role. After the deployment is done successfully. I can see my Luis app showing in my Azure portal.

**But I don't see the Luis app listed in the Authoring resource dropdown list in the LUIS.AI portal.**

Anyone, please help me understand why?

Is there any specific step do I need to do to link my LUIS app to the LUIS portal? or is this an issue with the ansible role/playbook that I am using?

Posted below is the ansible snippet I used to generate my Qnamaker and the Luis apps.

```
roles:
      - name: ansible-role-azure-cog-knowledge
        azure_cog_knowledge_search_sku: "basic"
        azure_cog_knowledge_baseservicesname: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      - name: ansible-role-azure-cog-language
        azure_cog_language_kind: LUIS
        azure_cog_language_sku: S0
        azure_cog_language_baseservicename: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        azure_cog_language_location: "southcentralus"
        azure_cog_language_account_key_secretnameprefix: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        azure_cog_language_service_name: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Please find my Luis portal screenshot posted below. My Luis app is expected to show in the  "Authoring Resource" dropdown list. But it is not.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? I believe I understand, but would like to be sure. I'm not very familiar with ansible...is there documentation that you're following? I notice that in my LUIS service's template, `kind` is `LUIS.Authoring` instead of just `LUIS` (like you have). Does it work if you change that?

Comment: How is this going? I'm not able to find anything that references the `azure_cog_language` packages, so I'm having difficulty troubleshooting this.

Comment: I tried with LUIS.Authoring , but then my build failed

Comment: Where are you finding the `azure_cog_language` packages?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, I am facing a similar issue. I created an authoring resource in the Luis portal, even got to import a few apps, then the authoring resource disappeared in the Luis portal. I can see the resource in the Azure portal. Is this something you can help?

Answer (score 0):

An Azure resource for LUIS provides billing and authentication to the LUIS service - it doesn't create an app.

An app, in LUIS, contains intents and entities. Accessing the app requires the app to the trained, published, and then use the prediction endpoint along with the predition runtime key.

A resource != app